# pod setup Cloning into 'master' error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to pod setup, but I am getting following error:

---

> [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth=1
>
> Cloning into 'master'...
>
> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed
>
> ---
>
> network status is ok.

I don't know what's going on.

Comment: the case has resolved.
==================
I try to download and install it home of colleagues, I think maybe is my network problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub has been having [issues](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2016/03/08/cocoapods-popular-basically-took-five-github-servers/#gref) with the Specs repo lately, see [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4989).

Comment: Thank you for help.
the issue has resolved. 
I try to download and install it home of colleagues, I think maybe is my network problems.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was forcing `git` to use `git://` instead of `https://`.

Add following to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "git://github.com/"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

This way `pod install` works for me too.

**UPDATE (2019-07)**

This answer is being down-voted recently - possibly it no longer works?

**UPDATE (2019-08)**

This is a working solution. Tested!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Only solution working at the moment from those proposed.

Comment: Works for install RealmSwift for now

Comment: Actually, it works very well for me too. Have been spending hours before I stumble upon this answer. 
Thanks for saving!

Answer (score 2):

After searching the solution for 3 days, here is the only solution worked for me. I just increased the buffer size of git global configuration and it worked like a charm.

1. Install Cocoapods
2. Set git buffer size: `git config --global http.postBuffer 2M`
3. run command: `pod setup`
4. You are done.